# numerical integration of a matrix with two variable on a path

Tags: function, variables, matrix, integration

I want to calculate the integration of a matrix over a path. This matrix is in fact dependent on two variables. the answer of this integral would be a vector. it is:
Fn=integral(-(q ) Wn dГ)
q is a constant. Wn is a 2D matrix, N*n, which N is the number of the points (x,y) and n is the number of source points which create element of function and refers to different columns of this matrix. for example W2(1,2) is the matrix function value at point (x1,y1) for the source n=2.
I cannot use "trapz" for calculation of this integral, because in trapz(X,Y) the X should be a vector but in my case the function Wn is dependent on two variable (x,y), So the X in trapz would be a matrix instead of a vector. 
how can I calculate this integral? 
also, how should I implement the path in the calculation of my integral. My current path for integral calculation is a vertical line at x=0, 0

so many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I should devide the boundary to strait lines between each 2 node,then calculate the integral using gauss-lojander method.